# как подключить к одному компьютеру несколько 4g роутеров

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, администрирование, роутер

как подключить несколько 4g роутеров к одному компьютеру и пользоваться при этом совокупной скоростью соединения от всех подключенных роутеров как единым каналом.

Comment: Зачем такой геморрой? у вас просто много роутеров или хотите быстрый интернет?

Comment: Создать несколько сетевых интерфейсов) А еще гуглить. На Linux файл настроек сети `/etc/network/interfaces` и католог `/etc/network/interfaces.d`. Ну и network manager.

Comment: Да и вообще, просто попробовать подключить оба 4G, посмотреть какие у них интерфейсы (`ip a`) и попробовать пропинговать их по очереди (типа `ping -Ieth0 1.1.1.1`)

Comment: Из ПО можно воспользоваться готовыми решениями типа pfSense. Из аппаратных в голову приходит  Zyxel Keenetic и, конечно же, **Microtic**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На роутерах назначьте разные ip адреса шлюзов, в настройках интерфейса уберите маршрут по умолчанию или назначьте метрику. Потом добавляете мультихоп маршрут с несколькими шлюзами:

```
ip route add default  proto static scope global \
 nexthop  via 192.168.0.1 weight 1 \
 nexthop  via 192.168.1.1 weight 1 \
 nexthop  via 192.168.2.1 weight 1 
...
```

и нат

```
iptables -t nat -A -j MASQUERADE
```

Закачки вроде торентов будут утилизировать несколько роутеров, но серфинг и потоковая передача будет идти через один произвольный.

Comment: Что значит утилизировать? Желательно что  бы всё взаимодействие с сетью шло по широкому каналу

Comment: @Gybernaty тут 4g роутеры- где ШПД? Изменяя вес можно регулировать распределение. ОС не знает какой канал широкий, а какой еле тащит. Поэтому такая схема подходит для сети с предсказуемыми задержками. Утилизировать = использовать полностью.

Comment: а если этот хост будет использован как распределительный для группы хостов?

Comment: что за распределительный?